# Swift 5: 'substring(to:)' is deprecated

Tags: swift, swift4, swift5

I`m newbie in Swift and  I have simple code, that cut string from the end to special characters "$2F" and returned cutted off string:

```
    let index2 = favUrlString.range(of: "%2F", options: .backwards)?.lowerBound
    favUrlString = index2.map(favUrlString.substring(to:))!
```

How I have to update this code to Swift 5?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `String Slicing` instead of `Substring`. like below

```
let yourString = "dummy string"
yourString[5..<yourString.count] // string
```

Comment: Do not post comments asking for votes. And this question should not have been answered. There are many duplicates.